# How does "echo $0" work?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

I found out on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-do-i-check-which-shell-i-am-using) I can use this command to figure out what shell I am in.

```
echo $0
```

I like this because it is simple as compared to more complex solutions like this one on the [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal) Stack Exchange.

I imagine `echo` is similar to print but what is the `$0`?

Eventually I would like to be able to open up multiple tabs programmatically similar to seen here on [Stack Overlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line).

That uses `gnome-terminal` but I am using Bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### $0 is a special parameter in Bash…

#### …and other [POSIX standards compliant shells](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) as well.

As explained in [this comment on that answer you link to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/590899/how-do-i-check-which-shell-i-am-using#comment1190270_590902), `echo $0` simply shows you the name of the currently running process:

> $0 is the name of the running process. If you use it inside of a shell then it will return the name of the shell. If you use it inside of a script, it will be the name of the script.

More details can be [found here on this other site](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$0):

> $0 is one of the [Bash special parameters](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Bash_special_parameters). It can only be referenced as follows (just an example as there are various ways to reference and use $0 while scripting).

So just create a Bash script like this. First open up a file for writing called `test.sh` with Nano like this:

```
nano test.sh
```

Then put these contents into that file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, save the file. Now make the script executable like this:

```
chmod 700 test.sh
```

Now run it like this:

```
./test.sh
```

And the output would be:

```
./test.sh
```

So for the purposes you describe `echo $0` won’t really work.